# NativeScript Firebase already initialized

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-plugin, nativescript-firebase

I am using Firebase in my app and I've noticed when I am actively making changes and LiveSync updates the app it will sometimes say "firebase.init error: Firebase already initialized". This happens when the changes don't trigger a whole application restart (ex. an html file). It completely messes up my current authentication state and forces me to restart the app anyways.

Is there some way I can catch for this happening or prevent it? I can try to make a demo app for it, but I feel this might have happened to somebody already.

I am just using the standard [firebase.init](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase#angular) as shown in the documentation in my app.component, nothing special or different.

Comment: https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase/issues/613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using on ngOnit of App.component, try to initlize firebase on [app launch](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/application-lifecycle) event.

```
applicationOn(launchEvent, (args: LaunchEventData) => {
    firebase.init({
   // Optionally pass in properties for database, authentication and cloud messaging,
  // see their respective docs.
  }).then(
function () {
  console.log("firebase.init done");
},
function (error) {
  console.log("firebase.init error: " + error);
}
 );
});
```

Comment: Since I have to run this code in main.ts I do not have access to my services because the app hasn't started, which are what handles the user being logged in and out.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by using a detached onAuthStateChanged in app.component `firebase.addAuthStateListener(listener)` and with testing if firebase.initialized is true, then I manually get the current user with firebase.getCurrentUser(). Round-about way, but it works.